# Accessibility issue caused by indentation code check

Tags: feature-request, review, code-formatting

I'm blind and I wrote some years ago about this issue but nothing was done, now I retry to submit this issue also because there is the reviewer role.
To understand my problem I can tell you that I lost one hour and half, more or less, for submitting this question:

[How use java.time.LocalDate using Hibernate5 and Vaadin8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44762884/how-use-java-time-localdate-using-hibernate5-and-vaadin8)

and the last thing that I deleted (but I don't know if it was only that the problem) was the tag .

Now my idea is this: you could add a checkbox to submit a question with this kind of problem and if the reviewer note that the problem isn't only  the indolence of the writer, should correct the question and confirm the submitting, if he find too much problems he could reject the question or correct it and give a bad vote.
What do you think about that?

Comment: "but nothing was done" is not a valid reason to submit a feature request again. You can edit your original feature request and add more details if you have such, but don't post whole new request just because nothing was done.

Comment: Please try to quote the error message by starting the line with `>`. Now I edited the question

Comment: @Shadow wizard well, I know that It's not a good idea but my previous question is 5 years old and, in the last comment, @@The Unhandled Exception  wrote that I should write a new question ... this is my old question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114325/check-for-the-indentation-code-control?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: He meant if you have any **new** problem then ask new question, you have the exact same problem. Look, I do feel sorry that it's so hard for you to format or indent code and wish it would be improved, but even so, the rules of this site must be kept.